# Difficulty in connecting to SFTP server with Python and Flask?

Tags: python, flask, server, sftp

I am trying to connect to an SFTP server but I am getting an error:

`pysftp.exceptions.ConnectionException: ('NAMEOFSERVER@sftp.NAMEOFHOST.gov', 22)`

I have no clue why this is happening, here is the portion of the code that is causing problems:

```
myHostname = "NAMEOFHOST"
myUsername = "" #there is no username
myPassword = "PASSWORD"

import pysftp

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()

cnopts.hostkeys = None
with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword,cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    print ("Connection succesfully stablished ... ")
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If there is no username, why don't you put None, instead of an empty string. None != ""

So:

```
myHostname = "NAMEOFHOST"
myPassword = "PASSWORD"

import pysftp

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()

cnopts.hostkeys = None
with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, password=myPassword,cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    print ("Connection succesfully stablished ... ")
```

Give it a try and say whether this solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! No, unfortunetally it did not work.... 

Do you think a VPN could be causing issues? The sftp I am trying to connect will only work with connections coming in through the government internet (i.e. at the location where I work) or with connections coming in through a special VPN. I am currently running the VPN on my computer, does that mean the connection that my website is using is also through the VPN? if that makes sense...

Comment: To be sure you should use a desktop application and test whether it works from your local computer. If it works, then there is no problem with the connection, thus you will need to rework your code. Give it a try and let me know.